# Interpreting various First Aid error messages

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, mojave, apfs

Can someone provide documentation or their own knowledge to interpret the below messages? I've researched this diligently but no post has the same combination of messages that I have. There are 5 types of messages. Posts online mention different combinations of them, but none with all 5 and just the five.

Here are the five types of messages output by Disk Utility's First aid after stating "Checking snapshot 1 of 14"

```
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (#####) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
```

where ##### is like “0x86e266 + 4”. There are 42 of these messages.

```
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (#####) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
```

where ##### is like “0x86e266 + 4”. There are 50 of these messages.

```
error: btn: invalid btn_btree.bt_key_count (expected 11503462, actual 11503483)
```

```
Snapshot is invalid
```

```
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 could not be verified completely.
```

The only message I can diagnose with some certainty is the fourth one, according to this [Apple Developer post](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:G9saYn3gFp4J:https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79385+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari), that says that some Time Machine snapshots were corrupted when Apple switched from the old file system to the new APFS.

I appreciate your help,

Raw First Aid output follows:

```
Running First Aid on “Macintosh HD” (disk1s1)

NOTE: First Aid will temporarily lock the startup volume.

Verifying file system.
Volume could not be unmounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by hfs_convert (748.21.6) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.250.134).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 14.
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29afd5 + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29afde + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29b165 + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29b4d6 + 3) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29b4e5 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29b56f + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c28c + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c295 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c298 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c29e + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c40d + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c416 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c423 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c428 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c542 + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c549 + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c88e + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29c894 + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29ccd6 + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29d793 + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29da3e + 6) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29da46 + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29dad1 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29dadc + 3) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29dbf3 + 3) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x29dcee + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f272 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f276 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f29f + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f2a8 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f2c9 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f2d8 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x44f314 + 2) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x812aa4 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x82deee + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x836441 + 1) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x86e266 + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x86e2be + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x86e2ca + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x86e2d6 + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x86e6ff + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : ExtentRef physical extent (0x86e77b + 4) has kind APFS_KIND_UPDATE but was not referenced previously
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e266 + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e2be + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e2ca + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e2d6 + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29afd5 + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29afde + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b165 + 3) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b168 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b4d6 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b4d7 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b4d8 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b4e5 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29b56f + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c28c + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c295 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c298 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c29e + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c40d + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c416 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c423 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c428 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c542 + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c549 + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c88e + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c894 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29c895 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29ccd6 + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29d793 + 3) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29d796 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e6ff + 4) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29da3e + 6) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29da46 + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29dad1 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29dadc + 3) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e77b + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x86e77d + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29dbf3 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29dbf4 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29dbf5 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x29dcee + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f272 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f276 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f29f + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x812aa4 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f2a8 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f2c9 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f2d8 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x82deee + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x836441 + 1) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: Cross Check : FSroot tree references extent (0x44f314 + 2) which is not present in the ExtentRef tree
error: btn: invalid btn_btree.bt_key_count (expected 11503462, actual 11503483)
Snapshot is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.
```

Comment: ever found an answer to any of these? escpecially the 2nd

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I posted this in the Apple forum and some of the vets gave this advice: that interpreting the messages is basically impossible for lay people. The real way to diagnose is to download some tool the community uses and post the output there so that the vets can diagnose it. I did that and I still didn’t get any answers. I took it to a local authorized Apple repair center and they diagnosed and fixed it in 24 hours. It cost $200. But I’ve been problem free for 6 months. It was the batteries. It just goes to show the problem is hard to guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I might go the same way